# Не удаётся ввести с клавиатуры в строковый элемент массива

Tags: c#

Хочу ввести с клавиатуры значения в строку, которая является элементом массива:`string words[1]=Console.ReadLine();`
Выдает ошибку, неудивительно.
Расскажите как это сделать, и как вообще правильно делать массив строк в C#?
Первый раз на C# пишу, не ругайтесь.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str_eng = "Apple,Sky";
            string[] words = str_eng.Split(',');
            string str_rus = "Яблоко,Небо";
            string[] words1 = str_rus.Split(',');
            string words[1]=Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Думаю проблема в том, что вы повторно объявляете переменную)

Comment: `string words[1]=Console.ReadLine();` уберите

Comment: А как тогда внести данные в строку?

Comment: @SHEVA достаточно из этой строчки `string words[1]=Console.ReadLine();` убрать `string`, либо же выбрать другое имя переменной

Comment: Зачем вам туда что-то вносить если `words[1]` уже имеет значение `Небо`

Comment: @uber42 `Sky`, если быть точнее)

Comment: Допустим не [1], а [4]

Comment: @dmepty Убрал String, ошибка пропала, но запись не происходит :с

Comment: @dmepty, да `Sky`, промахнулся)

Comment: Непонятно чего вы хотите добиться тем что вводите значения которые уже есть в массиве.

Comment: _запись не происходит_ - потому что количество элементов в массиве постоянное.

Comment: @SHEVA Только что пробовал у себя, всё работает. Если вы хотите добавлять записи, то нужно использовать `List<string>` и метод `Add`, т.к. массивы в C# не изменяемы и вам нужно задать размер массива при объявлении.

Comment: Я хочу ввести с клавиатуры значения в строку, которая яв-ся элементом массива. Как это сделать правильно? Приведите пожалуйста фрагмент кода в пример,  понимаю что в коде ошибок море, но в сети не нашел ничего путного по этой теме

Comment: @SHEVA Вы хотите добавить к уже существующему элементу массива новую строку?

Comment: Нет, в новый элмент

Comment: P.S. как указать размерность строки и количество строк в массиве? В c++ это делалось так: char str_rus[30][80], где 30 кол-во элементов, а 80 кол-во символов строке

Comment: @SHEVA Так же, как и на плюсах) Если вам нужно добавлять элементы в массив, тогда укажите его размерность и, собственно, добавляйте в свой удовольствие)

Comment: @dmepty совершенно верно указал, использовать `List<..>`, уйдите от массивов в понимании `C`, так же погуглите `Dictonary`. Там ещё масса полезных типов, которые заточены под разное применение.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ru_stack_owerflow_CA1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string strEn = "Apple,Sky";
            const string strRu = "Яблоко,Небо";
            List<string> wordsEngList = strEn.Split(',').ToList();
            List<string> wordsRuList = strRu.Split(',').ToList();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter you word: ");
            wordsEngList.Add(Console.ReadLine());

            foreach (string s in wordsEngList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("wordsEngList: " + s);
            }
            foreach (string s in wordsRuList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("wordsRuList: " + s);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

И одна из рекомендаций, попробуйте [ReShaper](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper), он поможет вам выявить ошибки при обучении. Да и в дальнейшем дает разумные подсказки :) [скачать](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) можно на родном сайте www.jetbrains.com

Answer (score 0):

```
void main()
{
    string[] words = {"one","two"};
    addEl(ref words);
}

void addEl(ref string[] mass)
{
    string newEl = Console.ReadLine();
    Array.Resize<string>(mass, mass.Length + 1);
    mass[mass.Length - 1] = newEl;
}
```

или

```
void main()
{
    List<string> str = new List<string>();
    addEl(str);
}   


void addEl(List<string> l)
{
    string newEl = Console.ReadLine();
    l.add(newEl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Более прикладной вариант

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] names = new string[3];

        //пока в массиве имен есть свободные позиции запрашиваем новые имена
        while (true)
        {
            //получение индекса в массиве где строка равна null
            int index = Array.IndexOf(names, null);
            //если индекс -1 значит массив заполнен => выходим из цикла
            if (index == -1) break;

            //присвоение имени, кот.ввели
            names[index] = GetNewName();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Готово!");
        Console.WriteLine("-------");

        //проходим по массиву и к кажд. элементу применяем вывод на консоль
        Array.ForEach(names, Console.WriteLine);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static string GetNewName()
    {
        string result = String.Empty;
        //пока не введена строка или ключевое слово "выйти" просим ввести имя
        while (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result)
            || String.IsNullOrEmpty(result) || result.Equals("выйти"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите имя: ");
            result = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```